# Different AWS snapshots in console vs CLI?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

When I use the CLI to look at my snapshots, I see many more than the ones I see in the AWS console. I also don't see ones listed on the CLI that are in the console. On the CLI, I am using:

```
aws ec2 describe-snapshots | sort -k 5 | grep 2014-07
```

Why aren't they the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the AWS documentation [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/describe-snapshots.html), `describe-snapshots` outputs public snapshots, a.o.
I believe what you want is:

```
aws ec2 describe-snapshots --owner-ids self
```